# error when running npm run dev on laravel + inertia + linux

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
> '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ] 2 info using npm@6.14.4 3 info using
> node@v10.19.0 4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ] 5
> info lifecycle @~predev: @ 6 info lifecycle @~dev: @ 7 verbose
> lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true 8 verbose lifecycle
> @~dev: PATH:
> /usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/html/SostLaravel/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin
> 9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: /var/www/html/SostLaravel 10 silly
> lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run development' ] 11 silly
> lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null 12 info lifecycle
> @~dev: Failed to exec dev script 13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `npm run development` 13 verbose stack Exit status 1 13 verbose stack
> at EventEmitter.
> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16) 13 verbose
> stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13) 13 verbose stack
> at ChildProcess.
> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14) 13
> verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13) 13 verbose
> stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16) 13 verbose
> stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (internal/child_process.js:259:5) 14 verbose pkgid @ 15 verbose cwd
> /var/www/html/SostLaravel 16 verbose Linux 5.4.0-135-generic 17
> verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev" 18 verbose
> node v10.19.0 19 verbose npm  v6.14.4 20 error code ELIFECYCLE 21
> error errno 1 22 error @ dev: `npm run development` 22 error Exit
> status 1 23 error Failed at the @ dev script. 23 error This is
> probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
> output above. 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Good morning, I've already cleared the cache, I've reinstalled npm, I've deleted node-modules and package-lock, I've done everything but everything results in this same error.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a good idea to check your node version and be sure its compatible with your packages.

Comment: I installed the same version of node that I use on windows, on windows it worked perfectly but on linux it is giving these problems, would it really be the node version?

Comment: running `npm install` works fine? also, can you share a snipet of your package.json